# Accessing the implicit objects from a JSP EL function

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When defining a function for the JSP expression language, is there a way to specify that the function requires one of the implicit objects (such as `pageContext`)?

I want to define a function `${my:href('a.jpg')}` to be implemented by

```
public static String href(String fileName, PageContext pageContext)
```

but I do not want to have to explicitly pass the pageContext to the function every time I call it.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the "implicit" objects only if you provide for stashing them (via a filter or something) as thread local variables. Then you can write some utility classes to go get them from whatever context makes sense. Some frameworks (Stripes, for example) (yaay Stripes!) make that relatively easy.

Comment: So you put the info object in some context (which probably uses a hash map somewhere). This makes it easy to locate the info object from anywhere but it's slow. My solution is much faster but less flexible.

Comment: It's not slow, and you don't need to put them in a hash map. (Well, not an explicit hash map, or a visible one anyway; it's all a matter of how ThreadLocal is implemented.)  You can use individual ThreadLocal variables to store different context objects, and access them via utility classes (singletons or static accessor functions). Strips lets you keep a single general context object around, from which you can get at anything you might need.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a tag instead of a function. Tags provides you implicit access to the `PageContext` by the inherited [`TagSupport#pageContext`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport.html#pageContext).

Comment: Yeah, I have a tag now, but I wanted to convert it to a function because `<a <my:href href='a.png' /> >` offends my XML sensibilities. And I did not want to go all the way and implement a complete `<my:a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice but no, there is no way to do that directly. Also, there is no workaround since JSP EL functions must be `public static`. So the solution is to go back to plain old JSP code:

```
<% Helper my= new Helper (pageContext); %>
```

`Helper` has a normal public method that takes a filename as argument:

```
public String href (String fileName) { ... }
```

and later

```
... ${my.href(...)}
```

Comment: There's no way to do it directly, but it's definitely possible to do it, and I make use of that extensively in my Java web app.

Comment: a scriptlet? really? -1